# How to Unload a popped view controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Using a navigation based view hierarchy. I have a root view controller, and multiple view controllers that branch out from the same when a button is pressed. When a user presses the back button on the UINavigationBar, the current viewcontroller is popped and the display animates back to the rootviewcontroller.

The problem is, I want the viewcontrollers to UNLOAD whenever they are popped. Seems like they are not unloading because when I go back to them they are still in the state they were when they were popped.

How do I unload the viewcontrollers after navigating back to the rootviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-viewUnload` is called after the application receives low-memory notification.

It is the default implementation of `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` that calls `-viewUnload`.

What you probably want to do is put what you want to do into `-viewDidDisappear` based on what you've described.

Comment: Ok so in -viewDidDissapear i should put something like [self dealloc]? Or what about this, in the rootviewcontroller, putting something like if(self.viewControllerOne !=nil){ self.viewControllerOne = nil;} ??

Comment: You shouldn't call dealloc manually. -dealloc is handled by the runtime. Release whatever you need to release in -viewDidDisappear.

Comment: What about the 'nil' suggestion I said?

Comment: That doesn't guarantee that will do what you want it to do.

Comment: It seemed to do the trick. I just am worried that it may cause probs later on down the line.

Answer (score 0):

When you pop a viewcontroller from a navigationcontroller, there should be no more references to the viewcontroller left and the viewcontroller should be deallocated at that time.  This should give you the results you expected.  You can test if the viewcontroller is being deallocated by adding a break point in **-dealloc** method.

If dealloc does not get called, check if there is a retain cycle.  Specifically check if a child object is retaining the viewcontroller.

Answer (score -3):

in -viewDidDisappear why not [self release]; just need to make sure you have a lazy loader so it will load back when needed.

Comment: Please use the search function to look for a similar question. I saw the exact same question about 20 min ago.